# Derivation of the dual of the linear assignment problem

Tags: linear-programming, lagrange-multiplier, duality-theorems, matching-theory

I read that the dual of the assignment problem is

$$
\begin{align} \text{maximize } & \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i + \sum_{i=1}^n \beta_i \\
& \lambda_i + \beta_j \leq c_{ij}
\end{align}
$$

where the primal problem is

$$
\begin{align}
\text{minimize } & \sum\limits_{i=i}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^n c_{ij}x_{ij} \\
&\sum_{i=1}^n x_{ij} = 1\; \forall j \\
&\sum_{j=1}^n x_{ij} = 1\; \forall i \\
&x_{i,j} ~\in (0,1)
\end{align}
$$

But unfortunately, I am not able to derive dual from primal using Lagrangian. Anyone can help ?

Comment: Would you please state clearly which are objective functions and which are constraints? I would expect to see $\min$ in the primal and I am puzzled by having $\le c_i$ after $\max \lambda_i + \beta_i$.

Comment: sorry.  there was a mistake. I corrected it now.